# display text on toggle button

Tags: css, checkbox, toggle

I have a simple checkbox toggle that change the background color when clicked or checked, that indicates active or not. My problem is I don't know how to put label on that button.

something like this.

[image]

I'm not sure if that possible.

I hope you understand me.

Thanks

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/MQoBqq)

```css
body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.toggle {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 65.57px;
  padding: 10px;
height: 26.32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E1F6FF;
  transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "text text";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 24px;
height: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-indent: -30px;
  word-spacing: 37px;
  color: #4D5585;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.7, 1) 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked {
  background: #dadce8;
}

.toggle:checked:before {
  left: 40px;
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
  
  </center>
```

Comment: Where is your white circle? are you talking about the checkbox square shape?

Comment: please check the snippet sir

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: not correct sir

Comment: I dont see any circle in the snippet sir, please please elaborate your question, I am not understanding.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achive desire result after edit, we are going to build something new.

> HTML

```
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" checked>
  <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch">
        <span class="switch-text"></span>
        <span class="switch-dot"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

We will use a main div with class `switch` to build our switch. This will hold 2 things

1. The input so we can target it state and use both for styles and what i suppose future js styles
2. A label that will hold 2 things

   2.1  The on and off text as `before` and `after` of a span

   2.2 The white dot that slides on each state

CSS is commented on the snippet

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/*Style main div and remove default checkbox*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.switch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}


/*Style words and oval switch */

.switch-labels {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.switch-text {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.switch-text:before,
.switch-text:after {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.switch-text:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #E1F6FF;
  color: #000000;
}

.switch-text:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #4D5585;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: right;
}


/*Style center dot*/

.switch-dot {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 41px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.switch-dot:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/multiply-icon-27981.png');
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}


/*State changer*/

.switch-checkbox:checked+.switch-labels .switch-text {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.switch-checkbox:checked+.switch-labels .switch-dot {
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" checked>
  <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch">
        <span class="switch-text"></span>
        <span class="switch-dot"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Like? Would we keep the curent text? Can the White space go bigger so the text fit?

Comment: @misdirection this is what i can come up with. Hope this is what you need. I'll go to rest, but please comment if you need anything else and i;ll be happy to tackle it in the morning

Comment: @misdirection happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the text in content for toggle.before to 
content: "hide show";

Comment: sorry sir, what I want is, is to put text on that white circle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just want to add labels?

use below inside `.toggle:before`

> content: "Hide Show";

instead

> content: "text text";

Thanks. Ask for more queries.

Comment: Have u tried my answer ?  for label you only need to change is content.
content: "Hide Show". Ask me more for your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the text on the white circle means , you can add this one in css

.toggle:before{

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand your question right way. Do you mean add a lebal to toggle this checkbox?

```css
body{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.toggle {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 65.57px;
  padding: 10px;
height: 26.32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E1F6FF;
  transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "text text";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 24px;
height: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-indent: -30px;
  word-spacing: 37px;
  color: #4D5585;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.7, 1) 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked {
  background: #dadce8;
}

.toggle:checked:before {
  left: 40px;
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  
  <input id="sample" class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="sample">This is a sample</label>
  
  </center>
```